# Best parameters to try while hyperparameter tuning in Decision Trees

Tags: python, scikit-learn, decision-trees

I want to post prune my decision tree as it is overfitting, I can do this using cost complexity pruning by adjusting ccp_alphas parameters however this does not seem very intuitive to me.

From my understanding there are some hyperparameters such as `min_samples_split`, `max_depth`, `min_impurity_split`, `min_impurity_decrease` that will prune my tree to reduce overfitting.

Since I am working with a larger dataset it takes a long time to train therefore don't want to just do trial-error.

What are some possible combinations of above mentioned hyperparameters that will prune my tree? + reasoning behind choosing particular combination will be helpful.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no combinations that work for all cases, hyperparameter tuning is still something that is mostly done by trial and error. Things like Gridsearch and Randomsearch exist though.

A good start is always the default setting. An idea if performance is an issue is to tune on a small percentage of the training set to later switch to the full set.